# Nginx log format - remove space after a variable

Tags: nginx, logging, format

Here's an example Nginx log format:

```
  log_format mylog '$request $request_time ms'
```

which will show something like `GET /foo 10 ms` and would be nicer if it showed `GET /foo 10ms`

Is there any way to remove the space after the `$request_time` variable. e.g. something like bash's `${request_time}ms`.

Comment: Have you tried that?

Comment: Think I should have, it actually works :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my surprise, the bash style actually works

```
 log_format mylog '$request ${request_time}ms'
```